# How do you define a protocol with a property in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to force all implementers of a protocol to implement a readonly property. This is my attempt:

```
@protocol Foo
@property(readonly) BOOL isPending;
@end

@interface Bar <Foo>
@end

@implementation Bar
- (BOOL) isPending {
    return NO;
}
@end
```

Why am I getting a warning in in the protocol file?

> Property 'isPending' requires method 'isPending' to be defined

It's a protocol! Protocols are not supposed to implement the functions! The classes who implement the protocol should implement the functions, which is exactly what I did.

Comment: Generally (following convention) I would declare that property like this `@property (readonly, getter=isPending) BOOL pending;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce the problem you're reporting under Xcode 4.3.2. Is it possible you've declared something to implement `Foo` but neglected to add a getter to it for `isPending`? A diagnostic might be to add `- (BOOL) isPending` to the protocol in place of the `@property` and see if there's any difference. You can still use dot syntax even with fully declared getters and setters so it shouldn't make a syntactic difference to any other part of your program.

Comment: +1 `Is it possible you've declared something to implement Foo but neglected to add a getter to it for isPending`

Comment: @Paul.s the warning is happening in the protocol, not Foo. Foo does have a getter for isPending.